# Distribution of 2D random vector, a function of the standard normal random vector

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, characteristic-functions

The question is to find the distribution of $(\mathbf{a}^TZ, \mathbf{b}^TZ)$ where $Z$ is the standard $n$-variate normal random vector and $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are orthogonal.

I've calculated $\phi_Z(\mathbf{t}) = \exp(-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{t}\mathbf{t}^T)$.

By definition, $\phi_Y(\mathbf{t}) = \mathbb{E}\exp[i(t_1 \mathbf{a}^{T}Z + t_2 \mathbf{b}^TZ)]$.

What should I do next?

- from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1765672/348586), $\mathbf{a}^TZ$ and $\mathbf{b}^TZ$ are normally distributed, but as they're both functions of $Z$, I don't think they're independent

Comment: Have you found out the mean and variance of $X = Za^{\top}$ and $Y = Zb^{\top}$? Also, try computing $\mathbb{E}[XY]$. What does that tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$X\sim N(\boldsymbol\mu, \boldsymbol\Sigma)$$

Then, the affine transformation of $X$:$$Y=\mathbf{c}+\mathbf{B}X$$ follows the normal distribution:

$$N\left(\mathbf{c} + \mathbf{B} \boldsymbol\mu, \mathbf{B} \boldsymbol\Sigma \mathbf{B}^{\rm T}\right).$$

In your case,

$$\boldsymbol\mu=\boldsymbol0, \boldsymbol\Sigma=\boldsymbol I, \boldsymbol c=\boldsymbol0, \boldsymbol B=\begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_n \end{pmatrix}.$$

Hence, $$\mathbf{B} \boldsymbol\Sigma \mathbf{B}^{\rm T}= \boldsymbol I.$$

The covariance matrix becomes the identity matrix, showing that $a^TZ$ and $b^TZ$ are independent.

You could directly compute the covariance of the two transformations as

$$\text{cov}(a^TZ, b^TZ)= a^T\boldsymbol I b=a^Tb=0.$$

As the joint distribution of them follows the bivariate normal distribution, they become independent if and only if their covariance is zero.

Comment: So the key is to observe that $a^TZ$ and $b^TZ$ follow centred normal distributions. Then after using the linearity of expectation, find that $\mathbb{E}(a^TZb^TZ) = 0$. The covariance matrix's main diagonal consists of $a^Ta$ and $b^Tb$ while the off-diagonal entries are 0. This corresponds to a bivariate normal distribution where $a^TZ$ and $b^TZ$ are independent. Is that right?

Comment: @johnsmith yes exactly. Here, the two points are that 1) any affine transformation of a normally distributed random vector again jontly follows a normal distribution and 2) some normally distributed random variables are independent iff they are uncorrelated ( their covariances are zero).